# I want to save the data from Elastic search 2.3.5 of product1 to Elastic search 6.2 of ProductV2

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch

I have two services first one is Product in which spring 4 and ElasticSearch 2.3.5 is used. Second service is ProductV2 in which Spring 5 and ElasticSearch 6.2 is used. I want to save the data from Elastic search 2.3.5 of product1 to Elastic search 6.2 of ProductV2. Please help me on this.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: All the data that is getting saved in Elastic search of Product1 service this data I have fetch using Spring AOP and data is saved in one object. This object I have converted into Json format. Object is having Arraylist of object. But I am not able to identify the a particular data is of which object in Json format. Please help me on this.